# Los datos visualizados desaparecen después de cambiar la vista con getView().setViewName() desde una acción en OpenXava

Tags: java, openxava

Uso setViewName() para cambiar la vista desde una acción y funciona, pero después de cambiar la vista todos los datos visualizados desaparecen, todos los campos se quedan en blanco.

Este es el código de mi acción:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    
    // ...
    // En este punto hay datos visualizados en la vista
    
    if (articulo.getGestionadoPor() == GestionadoPor.LOTE) {
        // Lote está definida como @View(name="Lote", members="...") en la entidad
        getView().setViewName("Lote"); 
    }
    else if (articulo.getGestionadoPor() == GestionadoPor.SERIE) {
        // Serie está definida como @View(name="Serie", members="...") en la entidad
        getView().setViewName("Serie");
    }
    
    // Ahora no se visualiza ningún dato aunque la vista sí que ha cambiado
}
```

¿Cómo puedo cambiar la vista y la vez conservar los datos visualizados?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llamas a View.setViewName() los datos visualizados se borran. Esto es porque OpenXava sólo carga los datos visualizados, por lo que si cambias a una vista que visualiza más datos, si mantuvieramos los datos, puede que obtuvieramos algunos campos en blanco que deberían tener valor.

Por esta razón tú eres el responsable de restaurar los datos después de cambiar la vista. Si estás seguro que las vistas Lote y Serie muestran exactamente los mismos datos (puede que con diferente distribución), entonces puedes coger los datos antes de cambiar la vista y después volverlos a poner. De esta manera:

```
// Cogemos los valores de la vista antes de cambiarla
Map valores = getView().getValues();

if (articulo.getGestionadoPor() == GestionadoPor.LOTE) {      
    getView().setViewName("Lote"); 
}
else if (articulo.getGestionadoPor() == GestionadoPor.SERIE) {
    getView().setViewName("Serie");
}

// Después volvemos a poner los valores
getView().setValues(valores);
```

Sin embargo, si las vistas visualizan datos diferentes la técnica de arriba no funciona bien. En ese caso, deberías obtener la clave de la entidad, cambiar la vista, restaurar la clave en la vista y refrescar desde la base de datos. Algo como esto:

```
// Obtenemos la clave antes de cambiar la vista
Map clave = getView().getKeyValues();

if (articulo.getGestionadoPor() == GestionadoPor.LOTE) {      
    getView().setViewName("Lote"); 
}
else if (articulo.getGestionadoPor() == GestionadoPor.SERIE) {
    getView().setViewName("Serie");
}

// Después asignamos la clave a la vista de nuevo
getView().setValues(clave);

// Y cargamos los datos desde la base de datos a partir de la clave
getView().findObject();
```